# RxSwift form validation and sending request in one stream

Tags: rx-swift

I have a case where I would like to validate form and then if everything is ok go to api request.

I've written some code and it works fine but errors dispose my stream. I know I could add .catch error at the end of flat map but then next flat map would be executed.

Can I add catch error at the end of stream without disposing it? Or the only way to deal with it is separate it to two streams validation and server responses?

```
        enum Response {
            case error(message: String)
            case success
        }

        let start = input.validate
            .withLatestFrom(input.textFields)
            .flatMap { [unowned self] fields -> Observable<String> in
                return self.validate(characters: fields)
            }
        .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] code -> Observable<String> in
            return self.apiClient.rxSendData(code)
                .retry(1)
        }
        .map { _ in return Response.success }
        .asDriver { Driver.just(Response.error(message: $0.localizedDescription)) }
```

Comment: Why does `validate(characters:)` return an Observable<String>? I would expect it to return a `Bool` (not an Observable<Bool>, but a simple Bool.)

Comment: No it returns code which is passed to the apiClient (which I haven't completed yet - it should be `rxSendData(code)`). When it fails it omits the sending data and it is caught by `asDriver { error }` code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions about code you aren't showing. Your `validate` function is especially odd to me. It looks like it emits a String (which is ignored, if validation was successful and doesn't emit anything (or maybe an error) if validation failed?

```
let start = input.validate
    .withLatestFrom(input.textFields)
    .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] fields -> Observable<String> in
        return self.validate(characters: fields)
            .catchError { _ in Observable.empty() } // empty() doesn't emit a value so the next flatMap won't be executed.
    }
    .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] _ -> Observable<Response> in
        return self.apiClient.rxSendData()
            .retry(1)
            .map { _ in Response.success }
            .catchError { error in Observable.just(Response.error(message: error.localizedDescription)) }
    }
    .asDriver { Driver.just(Response.error(message: $0.localizedDescription)) }
```

If `validate` emits an error when validation fails, and you want to capture that error, then something like this would work:

```
let start = input.validate
    .withLatestFrom(input.textFields)
    .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] fields -> Observable<Response> in
        return self.validate(characters: fields)
            .map { _ in Response.success }
            .catchError { Observable.just(Response.error(message: $0.localizedDescription)) }
    }
    .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] validation -> Observable<Response> in
        // here, the above flatMap emits a value no matter what, so we have to switch on it to determine if we want to continue or just push the Response down the pipe.
        switch validation {
            case .error:
                return Observable.just(validation)
            case .success:
                return self.apiClient.rxSendData()
                    .retry(1)
                    .map { _ in Response.success }
                    .catchError { error in Observable.just(Response.error(message: error.localizedDescription)) }
        }
    }
    .asDriver { Driver.just(Response.error(message: $0.localizedDescription)) }
```

Comment: I haven't completed my apiClient yet. It should take a `code: String` parameter like this `self.apiClient.rxSendData(code)`. Your code won't work because `.map { _ in Response.success }` shoud pass string only. I think my proper question should be: Can outer stream catch inner stream (flatMap) error without disposing it?

Comment: If that's your question, then the answer is no. If the flatMap emits an error, it's done. It will not emit anymore even if you catch the error later. You have to wrap the error in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the `materialize` operator? It converts an observable sequence into an observable sequence of event objects detailing what happened that cannot error but completes when the input sequence completes. You can then share that.

Something like:

```
let code = input.validate
    .withLatestFrom(input.textFields)
    .flatMap { [unowned self] fields -> Observable<String> in
        self.validate(characters: fields)
            .materialize()
    }
    .share(replay: 1)

code
    .compactMap { $0.error }
    .subscribe() // Show error from `self.validate`
    .disposed(by: bag)

let request = code
    .compactMap { $0.element }
    // Will get to this flat map only if `self.validate` did not error
    .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] code -> Observable<String> in
        self.apiClient.rxSendData(code)
            .retry(1)
            .materialize()
    }
    .share(replay: 1)

request
    .compactMap { $0.error }
    .subscribe() // Show error from `self.apiClient.rxSendData`
    .disposed(by: bag)

request
    .compactMap { $0.element }
    // Do something as a result of the request being successful
```

The chains would not cease upon `self.validate` and `self.apiClient.rxSendData` emitting errors.

Comment: Yes, Finally I ended up with something like this. Thanks